# How do you solve for a matrix by rearranging a matrix equation?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I am struggling with how you manipulate a matrix equation to solve for another. For example, I am trying to find the matrix that satisfies a given set of eigenvalues and eigenvectors, and I know that: $$ \mathbf{P^{-1}AP=D}$$
But how would I go about solving for matrix $ \mathbf{A}$?
I see in the book it is given as:
$$ \mathbf{A=PDP^{T}} $$
but not really sure how they got to that.

Comment: Hint: how would you do this in the ordinary, not-matrix case? (Remember that matrix multiplication does not commute). Also, you need to be careful: is $P$ symmetric or not?

Comment: @SeanRoberson I think you mean to ask if $A$ is symmetric

Comment: No, P is not symmetric, but the matrix I want, A, is.

Comment: @rays In the context of this question, $P$ satisfies $P^{-1} = P^T$. So, the question really amounts to asking why $P^{-1}AP = D$ can be rewritten as $A = PDP^{-1}$, which is what the linked question answers.

Comment: Also looking at it again, I feel like the book made an error and should say P^-1 instead of P^T on the RHS. Since when they solved the problem in the solutions, it appears they took the inverse, not transpose.